# Exothermic Rapid Multistage Reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, combustion

I asked a similar question on SpaceExploration, but I think it might be better answered here:
Most chemical reactions in rocket combustion sequences are fairly simple, even with "exotic" fuels like Diborane etc.

For instance: N2H4 + NTO, which forms a relatively small number of light, fast-moving products.

(For background; Rockets usually depend on multiple tanks (2-3), to store propellants, but this adds mass.)
To solve this and still have a fairly high-performance engine, a single storable propellant is required.
Such a propellant would likely be organic, and would need to be able to decompose upon contact with a catalyst into products that then combust hypergolically (upon contact, and relatively quickly.

I can't think of any reaction quite like this, but maybe I'm missing some clear and obvious reason for this being a pointless goal...
Also, I'm not asking for the sake of making such a thing, this is purely theoretical.

Comment: H2O2 was used for this, but the performance is below binary fuel.

Comment: You're missing that it's hardly a big deal and should have just read up on (mono)propellants. BTW " into products that then combust hypergolically" in there isn't making much sense - what decomposed is already "burnt" - that's essentially the point of explosives and monopropellants.

Comment: gun powder, ammonium nitrate, nitroglycerine. The only effective method is antigravity but thinking about it your destination would repel you! Possibly the effective use of dark matter; it seems to be accelerating everything else. It is frustrating trillions of galaxies, all that gravity and we are stuck on a small planet or a solar system.